# Write an image to a flash drive under OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd, block-device

Under Linux, I can simply do a:

```
dd if=ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

and boot up the /dev/sdb which is a device for a flash drive. It finishes in 263 seconds.

But: If I boot up an OpenBSD 5.6 and do the same (for the same flash drive, zeroed it between the two tests):

```
dd if=ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/rsd1i
```

It takes about half an hour to finish (using securelevel 1), but when I boot up the flash drive from it the BIOS only says:

```
no active partition found
```

**Question:** what am I missing?

Comment: `/dev/rsd1i` - I don't know how OpenBSD names drives, but that `1i` makes me think that's a partition of that disk, not the disk itself.

Comment: @muru I believe you are correct. Why don't you post as an answer

Comment: @ChrisMendez I would, if I had any experience with OpenBSD at all, or if I could explain the speed difference. With neither, all I have is a guess. :( If you post one, I'd +1 it, though.

Comment: You should pass a blocksize to use with `dd` in such cases, e.g. `dd bs=512k ...` for 512KB blocks, that should speed it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong partition letter. Try with this:

```
dd if=yourisofile.iso of=/dev/rsd1c
```

Replace 1 by the correct number of your device (search this info in the dmesg). Read the [Wikipedia article about BSD disklabels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_disklabel#The_contents_of_disklabels) to learn why with the `c` works and with `i` doesn't.